# How to delete lines in log file older than 14 days?

Tags: bash, logging, awk

I have a log that looks like this:

```
2018-09-18 03:29:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249
2018-09-18 03:34:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249 
2018-09-18 03:39:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249
```

I'm trying to use bash or another scripting language to delete all lines older than 14 days. Anyone have suggestions on how to do this? I've looked at GNU awk, but the examples weren't the most easy to run and still be readable.

Comment: It's better to use logrotate.

Comment: Hmm, why can't I add the gawk tag?

Comment: @JamesBrown [tag:gawk] is a synonym for [tag:awk]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ cat file
1818-09-18 03:29:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249
2018-09-18 03:34:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249
```

Using GNU awk and [`mktime()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    now=systime()        # now in epoch time
    fn=60*60*24*14       # fortnight in seconds
}
{
    dt=$1 " " $2         # create datetime
    gsub(/[:-]/," ",dt)  # replace - and : with space for mktime() (see doc above)
}
mktime(dt)>now-fn        
' file
```

Output:

```
2018-09-18 03:34:38 [info]: /up request - ip: 63.143.42.249
```

Promise that you spend the time I saved you to study awk.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk` and `date`:

```
awk -v d="$(date -d "14 days ago" "+%F%T")" '$1 $2 > d' file
```

Or, for improved readability

```
fortnight="$(date -d "14 days ago" "+%F%T")"
awk -v d="$fortnight" '$1 $2 > d' file
# or, depending on your taste
awk  '$1 $2 > d'  d="$fortnight"  file
```